# How can I change app's thumbnail in the taskbar? SFML 2.4

Tags: visual-c++, sfml

Someone know how can I change or make a **thumbnail** in SFML 2.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution can be quickly found on SFML documentation page, [here.](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Window.php#a63af61e026fba08e3153fd013620bcc0)
sf::RenderWindow::setIcon() method can give the application window an icon, however the actual icon must be represented by a pointer to an array of pixels.

This can be achieved by creating a .rc header file and a .c file containing the pixel array. The array can be created using GIMP's "C-Source image dump" ability.

Example:

The .rc file:

```
//icon.rc
IDR_APP_ICON ICON "icon.ico"
GLUT_ICON ICON "icon.ico"
```

The .c file:

```
//icon.c

/* GIMP RGBA C-Source image dump (icon.c) */

static const struct {
  unsigned int   width;
  unsigned int   height;
  unsigned int   bytes_per_pixel; /* 2:RGB16, 3:RGB, 4:RGBA */ 
  unsigned char  pixel_data[32 * 32 * 4 + 1];
} gimp_image = {
  32, 32, 4,
  "k\177h\377k\177h\377\377\377\377\0\377\377\377\0\377\377\377\0\204`\236\201"`

//The array pixel array would continue here until }; closing the struct.
```

The generated struct object can be then passed as an argument to the setIcon() method.

```
sf::RenderWindow::setIcon(gimp_image.width, gimp_image.height, gimp_image.pixel_data);
```

And icon.c file should be included in your main.cpp file or wherever it is you set the icon to the RenderWindow.